# Sitecore media library does not render with sc_language

Tags: media-library, multilingual, versions, mediaurls

I uploaded Versioned image in `Sitecore 10.0.1` media library.
Template used is - `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned/Image`

the image URL is also correctly rendered with `sc_lang`.
But when I browse the site, only the En image is shown across all `sc_lang`.
Is this a bug in Sitecore or is there any way to fix this?
I cleared Sitecore cache a lot of times too.

**Update:** If I open incognito and search the site first in the Spanish language, it correctly fetches Spanish images. but then I go back to English and it remains the Spanish image itself.

Comment: Do you have any caching? Or custom language resolver? When you open first in EN lang, media link contains `sc_lang=en`, and then you switch to ES and media link is still `sc_lang=en` or `sc_lang=es` but EN image is rendered anyway?

Comment: When I swicth to ES, media link changes to sc_lang=es but but EN image is rendered

Comment: And if you copy link to es image and open it in private tab, it shows es image correctly?

Comment: No even then it shows EN image only

Comment: But if you open the whole page with ES image and es language in incognito, it's ES image rendered? or if you open once EN page, it's always EN image no matter if you open ES page later in incognito?

Comment: Even in that case also, its En renedered. Suppose i do a lot of recycle and then restrt my compuetr and first search for ES then it will show ES image. After that, other language pages shows only ES images. I am fetching the image using this code